# AppWidget Deletion from Home Screen in android

Tags: android, kotlin, appwidgetprovider

I have weather app when i need to show an AppWidget on Home Screen , I could pull it from widgets and stick it to my device's home screen , the issue is that when i delete the widget , i no longer can find in my home screen widgets , tried to uninstall app and install it again , still not able to find the widget , i appreciate your help to find a solution for this issue . Thank you

- My AppWidget Class

```
 class WeatherWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {


    override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)

        appWidgetIds?.forEach { appWidgetId ->
            updateWidget(context!!, appWidgetManager!!,appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    private fun updateWidget(context: Context,appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,appWidgetId : Int){
        val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName,R.layout.app_widget_layout)

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.weatherRain,
            Utils.getWeatherData(context)["rain"].toString()
        )
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.weatherWind,
            Utils.getWeatherData(context)["wind"].toString()
        )
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.weatherHumidity,
            Utils.getWeatherData(context)["humidity"].toString()
        )

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,remoteViews)

    }


}
```

- Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/app_widget_layout"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/app_widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="350dp"
    android:minWidth="150dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/cloudy_sunny"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"/>
```

- Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".di.WeatherApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Learning"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".widgets.WeatherWidget"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter >
                <action
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/weather_app_widget" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

- 